# CSS3 - Transition with animation?

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

Here I have an animation that makes a blinking border next to the title you're hovering on:

```
#link_list a:hover {
border-left: 10px solid #E3E3E3;
animation: blink 1s infinite;
-webkit-animation: blink 1s infinite;
-moz-animation: blink 1s infinite;
-o-animation: blink 1s infinite;
animation-delay: 0.5s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes blink {
0%  { border-left: 10px solid rgba(215, 215, 215, 1); }
    50% { border-left: 10px solid rgba(215, 215, 215, 0); }
        100% { border-left: 10px solid rgba(215, 215, 215, 1); }
}
```

Now, the problem is that the transition doesn't support the animation.

I already fixed it for the transition-in with the `animation-delay` property, but the transition-out doesn't work because the animation is running.

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZNh9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack way to do this, but you can accomplish the effect you are looking for with positioning.

Basically, instead of setting the border width to be 0px when the links are not being hovered, set the width to 10px (the same as onHover) and use relative positioning to move the element to the left 10px, as if the border is not there.

Then set the animation of the `left` property to be `0.2s ease` and set `left: 0` in the :hover state.

```
#link_list  a{
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    transition: border-left 0.2s ease, border-bottom 0.2s ease, border-right 0.2s ease, left 0.2s ease;    
    position: relative;
    left: -10px;
}

#link_list a:hover {
    left: 0px;
}
```

With this, you can remove the transition-delay as well.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZNh9/2/)

Comment: Took me while to get it working properly, but this still works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  **`left: -10px;`** property instead of **`transition-delay: 0.2s;`** animation properties, add this properties into **`things #link_list  a{ }`**,

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZNh9/4/)**</kbd>

#### CSS

```
#link_list  a{
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 0px solid transparent;
    border-width: 0px;
    transition: border-left 0.2s ease, border-bottom 0.2s ease, border-right 0.2s ease;
    left: -10px;    // ADD THIS NEW
}
```

Comment: But then it stops flashing after the first time. I think the OP wants it to keep flashing until the user mouses out.

Comment: Thank you @David for inform me. really appreciate for your help.:)

Comment: @David you saved me from commenting that myself.